# Inline equations in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint, equations

Is it really true that there is no way at all to insert equations (either Word 2007 math or the old Equation Editor) "inline" in a PowerPoint 2007 slide?

It certainly seems to be so, but I have a hard time believing that the users have accepted this for so long when I'm sure I've done this in word processors as early as 1997.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct -- PowerPoint 2007 does not allow inline graphics of any kind, including equations. The only work-around of which I'm aware is in this article on using MathType with PowerPoint: http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/works_with.htm?target=powerpoint (scroll down near the bottom, to the section on animating equations, and look for the section below the screen shots of PPT 2003 and PPT 2004).

Comment: PowerPoint 2010 has finally rectified this however...

Comment: Hmm, yes, I ended up doing something similar: Instead of putting PowerPoint bullets in the "content" placeholder, I embedded a Word 2007 document into it, and did basically the whole slide in Word.

Answer (score 0):

In all honestly, I am not sure as I have never tried and it has been a while since I last used Power Point.

That being said, unless you get a better answer I would suggest one of three things:

1) Create it in Word or elsewhere normally and then try to copy and paste it in to Power Point, just in case it is there and supported, but the option/input is missing.

2) Create it in Word or elsewhere and try to import the item as an object / document.

3) Last resort, take a screenshot and paste it as a picture in to the slide show.

Comment: None of those seem to solve the "inline" part of the problem. At least, I haven't been able to figure out how to make Objects or Pictures inline in PowerPoint either, and I've read that pasting a Word equation into PowerPoint makes it a Picture anyway.